# JQuery .find() with multiple criteria

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add multiple criteria to JQuery find() and couldn't make any progress.

Working code

```
$("#left-menu-bar").find("li:not(.login)").each(function(){loadframe(this);})
```

I'm trying to add logout class as well to the above find criteria and couldn't make it work.

My attempt:

```
$("#left-menu-bar").find("li:not(.login)").find("li:not(.logout)").each(function(){loadframe(this);})
```

Comment: Any error you see in the browser devtool console? What is not working ? let us know please.

Comment: First line of code is returning all the ListItems that matches the selection criteria. where as the second line of code is not returning anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple `CSS` selectors in `not()`, so just change your selector to this:

```
$("#left-menu-bar").find("li:not(.login,.logout)").each(function(){loadframe(this);})
```

Comment: Yoo.. That is easy peasy.. Thanks much !!! You saved a lot of time. I regret not posting it earlier. :)